# Apex Legens API

Tags: api

I want to use the web api for Apex Legends, but I can't find anything about this.

Apex Legends is an EA game, but I don't find a section for this game in EA sport API.

Does anyone have related docs for this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no public API at the moment.

Here is a discussion you could follow about this topic:
https://answers.ea.com/t5/General-Discussion/Stats-API/td-p/7419174/page/1